# Why Java doesn't support structures ? (Just out of curiosity)

Tags: java, struct

I know you can use public fields, or some other workarounds. Or maybe you don't need them at all. But just out of curiosity why Sun leave structures out.

Comment: Because Java and C family are not the same language. Furthermore, it has classes, C don't, so there was a need for structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Java can support arbitrarily many kinds of classes, the Runtime only supports a few variable types: int, long, float, double, and reference; additionally, the Runtime only recognizes a few object types: byte[], char[], short[], int[], long[], float[], double[], reference[], and non-array object.  The system will record a class type for each reference variable or array instance, and the Runtime will perform certain checks like ensuring that a reference stored into an array is compatible with the array type, but such behaviors merely regard the types of objects as "data".

I disagree with the claim that the existence of classes eliminates the need for structures, since structures have semantics which are fundamentally different from class objects.  On the other hand, from a Runtime-system design perspective, adding structures greatly complicates the type system.  In the absence of structures, the type system only needs eight array types.  Adding structures to the type system would require the type system to recognize an arbitrary number of distinct variable types and array types.  Such recognition is useful, but Sun felt that it wasn't worth the complexity.

Given the constraints under which Java's Runtime and type system operate, I personally think it should have included a limited form of aggregate type.  Much of this would be handled by the language compiler, but it would need a couple of features in the Runtime to really work well.  Given a declaration

```
aggregate TimedNamedPoint
{ int x,y; long startTime; String name; }
```

a field declaration like `TimedNamedPoint tpt;` would create four variables: `tpt.x`, `tpt.y` of type `int`, `tpt.startTime` of type `long`, and `tpt.name` of type `String`.  Declaring a parameter of that type would behave similarly.

For such types to be useful, the Runtime would need a couple of slight additions: it would be necessary to allow functions to leave multiple values on the stack when they return, rather than simply having a single return value of one the five main types. Additionally, it would be necessary to have a means of storing multiple kinds of things in an array. While that could be accomplished by having the creation of something declared as `TimedNamedPoint[12]` actually be an `Object[4]` which would be initialized to identify two instances of `int[12]`, a `long[12]`, and a `String[12]`, it would be better to have a means by which code could construct a single array instance could hold 24 values of type `int`, 12 of type `long`, and 12 of type `String`.

Personally, I think that for things like `Point`, the semantics of a simple aggregate would be much cleaner than for a class.  Further, the lack of aggregates often makes it impractical to have a method that can return more than one kind of information simultaneously.  There are many situations where it would be possible to have a method simultaneously compute and report the sine and cosine of a passed-in angle with much less work than would be required to compute both separately, but having to constructing a `SineAndCosineResult` object instance would negate any speed advantage that could have been gained by doing so.  The execution model wouldn't need to change much to allow a method to leave two floating-point values on the evaluation stack when it returns, but at present no such thing is supported.

Comment: I think it's worth asking what is a structure? In c++ a struct has little difference from a class. In C# a struct is very different, allowing allocation on the stack(value type) instead of the heap(reference type) something I feel Java is missing.

Comment: @ZackOfAllTrades: In C++, class and struct are essentially synonyms except for the default access level (if access levels of members are explicitly specified, they behave identically).  In C#, a struct will behave essentially in the fashion I describe as an "aggregate", but with quite a bit of additional complexity to allow such types to be efficiently used as generic arguments.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/simple-142616.html) that explains Sun's decision:

> **2.2.2 No More Structures or Unions**
>
> Java has no structures or unions as complex data types. *You don't need structures and unions when you have classes*; you can achieve the same effect simply by declaring a class with the appropriate instance variables.

Comment: What about the notion of structs as value types, as it happens with .Net?

Comment: Thanks, but also at first they throw enum out, and since 1.4 they introduce them.

Comment: @malakrsnaslava But what's your point? Enums have a very well-defined usage that was not possible using existing language features - it was a great asset to add them to the language. They were added in Java 5 by the way.

Comment: Enums were a new feature that offered various benefits, like clearer code and type-safety. Coders were finding situations where real enums would be useful, and the existing solutions were not as useful. A struct in Java would be the same as a struct in C++: a class. It would not offer much more in the way of clearer APIs or client code, or add anything in the way of type-safety. There might be a JSR for adding general-purpose structs to the specification, but I can't imagine it would get much traction.

Comment: In .NET, structs are treated like value types, which makes them extremely useful. Two of the major reasons why I won't use Java is because of it's implemention of Enums, and the vast chasm caused by it's erroneous lack of a value type. The thought of Initializing thousands of simple objects in a Java for loop, reading from a file, or programming a database caching mechanism without structs makes me cringe every time.